# Scrape total pages from a search term on a website

Tags: vb.net, winforms, pagination

I'm scraping content from `https://thepiratebay.se` and I'm wondering how I can get the total amount of pages of a search result.

This is my program:
[image: thepiratebay scraper]

As you can see to the left the scraped search results come up, and to the right are the comments on the selected result (which in this case is the top result). In the bottom part of the program you can see that it shows how many results it shows, now to the right of that are the pages.

I want to to show how many pages there are for a result in this format `{current page}/{total pages}`. I don't really want help finding `current page`, but I really want to get `total pages`.

I would also like this functionality for the comments (the list on the right).

This may be a little too much to ask, but it shouldn't really be so hard since getting the results is easy. Couldn't find anything on Google either, so your help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Scraping results:

```
Dim ResultCount, I As Integer
    Dim filenamelist, fileurllist, fileseeders, fileleechers, filemagneturl, filesize As New List(Of String)

    filenamelist.Clear()
    fileurllist.Clear()
    TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()

    Using WC As New System.Net.WebClient
        Source = WC.DownloadString("http://thepiratebay.se/search/" & TextBox1.Text.Replace(" "c, "%20") & "/0/7/")
        Link = Source
        If CheckBox6.Checked = True Then
            Source = Source & "600"
        End If
        If CheckBox5.Checked = True Then
            Source = Source & "500"
        End If
        If CheckBox7.Checked = True Then
            Source = Source & "400"
        End If
        If CheckBox4.Checked = True Then
            Source = Source & "300"
        End If
        If CheckBox3.Checked = True Then
            Source = Source & "200"
        End If
        If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
            Source = Source & "100"
        End If
        If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            Source = Source & "0"
        End If

        If Source.Contains("No hits. Try adding an asterisk in you search phrase.") Then
            MessageBox.Show("Search returned 0 results.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
        Else
            ResultCount = InstanceCount(Source, "vertTh")
            Dim Filename, FileUrl, Filemagnet, FS As String
            Dim FileSeed, FileLeech As Integer

            Do Until I = ResultCount
                Filename = GetBetween(Source, "title=" & Chr(34) & "Details for ", Chr(34) & ">", I)
                FileUrl = "http://thepiratebay.se/torrent/" & GetBetween(Source, "<a href=" & Chr(34) & "/torrent/", Chr(34) & " class=" & Chr(34) & "detLink" & Chr(34), I)
                FileSeed = GetBetween(Source, "<td align=" & Chr(34) & "right" & Chr(34) & ">", "</td>", I + I)
                FileLeech = GetBetween(Source, "<td align=" & Chr(34) & "right" & Chr(34) & ">", "</td>", I + I + 1)
                Filemagnet = "magnet:" & GetBetween(Source, "<a href=" & Chr(34) & "magnet:", Chr(34) & " title=" & Chr(34) & "Download this torrent using magnet", I)
                FS = GetBetween(Source, ", Size", ", ULed by ", I).Replace(" ", "").Replace("&nbsp;", " ")

                filemagneturl.Add(Filemagnet) 'add result to array
                filenamelist.Add(Filename) 'add result to array
                fileurllist.Add(FileUrl) 'add result to array
                fileseeders.Add(FileSeed) 'add result to array
                fileleechers.Add(FileLeech)
                filesize.Add(FS)
                I = I + 1 'increment i with 1 to get next result

            Loop
        End If
    End Using

    I = 0
    Do Until I = filenamelist.Count()
        Dim rootNode = TreeView1.Nodes.Add(filenamelist(I))
        rootNode.Nodes.Add("Seeders: " & fileseeders(I))
        rootNode.Nodes.Add("Leechers: " & fileleechers(I))
        rootNode.Nodes.Add(fileurllist(I))
        rootNode.Nodes.Add(filemagneturl(I))
        rootNode.Nodes.Add(filesize(I))
        I = I + 1
        LabelResults.Text = "Results: " & I
    Loop
```

Scrape comments on a result:

```
Try
        UsernameArr.Clear()
        PostArr.Clear()

        Using WC As New System.Net.WebClient
            Dim Source As String = WC.DownloadString(Link)
            Source = GetBetween(Source, "<div id=" & Chr(34) & "comments" & Chr(34) & ">", "<div class=" & Chr(34) & "ads" & Chr(34) & " id=" & Chr(34) & "sky-banner" & Chr(34) & ">", 0)
            Dim CommentCount As Integer = InstanceCount(Source, "byline")
            CommentCounter = CommentCount
            If CommentCount < 1 Then
                MessageBox.Show("This torrent has no comments")
            Else
                Dim itterator As Integer = 0

                Do Until itterator = CommentCount
                    Dim User As String = GetBetween(Source, "<a href=" & Chr(34) & "/user/", "/" & Chr(34) & " title=" & Chr(34) & "Browse ", itterator)
                    Dim Post As String = GetBetween(Source, "comment" & Chr(34) & ">", "</div>", itterator).Replace("<br />", " "c)
                    Dim DateStr As String = GetBetween(Source, "</a> at ", " CET:", itterator)

                    UsernameArr.Add(User)
                    postdatearr.Add(DateStr)
                    PostArr.Add(Post)

                    Dim rootNode = TreeView2.Nodes.Add(User)
                    rootNode.Nodes.Add(DateStr)
                    rootNode.Nodes.Add(Post)

                    itterator = itterator + 1
                Loop
            End If
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        'do nothing
    End Try
```

Get text between strings:

```
Private Function GetBetween(ByVal input As String, ByVal str1 As String, ByVal str2 As String, ByVal index As Integer) As String
    Dim temp As String = Regex.Split(input, str1)(index + 1)
    Return Regex.Split(temp, str2)(0)
End Function
```

Comment: Could you include your current pagination code?

Comment: Well, I don't have one. This is the code that gets the pages or am I not getting what you mean?

Comment: Ok. Could you at least show the code you're using to populate the search results/comment lists? That might help make it easier to figure out how to add pagination support.

Comment: Updated the thread with the code.

Comment: Uh yeah, this looks like it'll take some time. I'll be off to bed and will be looking at this thread in some hours, I would be so happy if you make this work :D

Comment: Anyone who could answer yet?